# Save a user-input from a textfield inside a tableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

Not sure but maybe I just missed the easy way...
What I am trying to achieve is: 
I have a tableView with a tableViewCell, in this tableViewCell I have a textfield in which the user can make an Input, I want to save that input when he clicks a button. 
I know how to do this with the prepareForSegue function but I want do it just with the Button Action. Is that possible? Or other question, when I use the didSelectRowAtIndextPath function, can I directly access the content of the cells outlet, textfields, labels, buttons....?

Thanks for any comments...

Comment: Are you trying to get only a PARTICULAR text from a PARTICULAR cell's textfield?? or all the text's from all the cells

Comment: Well, it is only one cell for now, so the text from that one cell's textfield.

Comment: Have you added the textfield and the button on the same cell of the table view. If so give a specific tag to the text field and then in the button click action try : ((UITextField *)[button.superview ViewWithTag:textfieldtag]).text to access the text.

Comment: Yes, they are on the same cell but so far I couldn't get that worked..